# Button that adds the selected value to a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a list of "Select" photos that by choosing one I can press a button and add some code to a textarea along with the chosen value.

I wrote this html code with external "JS" file but not being familiar with javascript I don't understand where I'm wrong.
I looked around a bit but I only found examples with jquery and that operate on on.change, while I need the value to be entered when the button is pressed plus must add the additional text along with the choice.

I would like to avoid using JQuery for a matter that this code has to run locally without being updated.

```js
function Art_AddFoto() {
  var Fotoselect = document.getElementById('art_fotoselect');
  var Selectvalue = Fotoselect.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

  var TextArea = document.getElementById('i251x');
  TextArea.innerText += '<img src="' + Selectvalue + "' alt='Image'>";
});
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea" style="height:200px;" name="art_testo" id="i251x"> </textarea>

<select class="select" name="art_fotoselect" id="art_fotoselect">
  <option value="test1">value1</option>
  <option value="test2">value2</option>
</select>

<div style="width:40%; display:inline-block;">

  <input type="button" name="Art_AddFoto" value="Aggiungi Foto" onclick="Art_AddFoto()" class="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Assign to `TextArea.value`, not `innerText`.

Comment: You have an extra `)` after the function definition. This code won't even run.

Comment: Yeah, the extra `);` at the end is a problem for us. Maybe you copy/pasted from a larger block that we can't see?

Comment: Right its work thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close!

The only change I had to make to your code was swapping `select` for `Fotoselect`:

```
function Art_AddFoto() {
    var Fotoselect = document.getElementById('art_fotoselect');
    var Selectvalue = Fotoselect.options[Fotoselect.selectedIndex].value;

    var TextArea = document.getElementById('i251x');
    TextArea.innerText += '<img src="' + Selectvalue + "' alt='Image'>";
}
```

Comment: Why not just `Fotoselect.value`?

Comment: Yep, `Fotoselect.value` is good, too.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt Thank you for the answer and correction  I dont know why bu doesnt work

Comment: if I use <a onclick="Art_AddFoto()">Add foto</a> work but not if I use <button onclick="Art_AddFoto()"> or <input type="button" onlick="Art_AddFoto()">
Anyway thank you

Comment: I tryed again with <input type="button" and now work maybe I put some char where make the problem.

Comment: Hooray! I'm glad it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Here can be a good start for you:

It use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
Art_AddFoto = (e) => {
document.querySelector('#i251x').value += document.querySelector('#art_fotoselect').value+"\r\n";
}

document.querySelector("#Art_AddFotoBtn").addEventListener('click',()=>{
Art_AddFoto(this)
})
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea" style="height:200px;" name="art_testo" id="i251x"></textarea>

<select class="select" name="art_fotoselect" id="art_fotoselect">
                <option value="test1">value1</option>
                <option value="test2">value2</option>
</select>

<div style="width:40%; display:inline-block;">

    <button name="Art_AddFoto"class="button" id="Art_AddFotoBtn">Aggiungi Foto</button>
</div>
```